# Get the return value of JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

My JOptionPane code is as follows:

```
selectedSiteName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the new site:");
```

This renders out an input with a textbox and an OK and Cancel button. I need to detect if Cancel was clicked.

Cheers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check if selectedSiteName == null .  
This will be the case if the user clicks Cancel or closes the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Read the JOptionPane API and follow the link to the Swing turorial on "How to Use Dialogs" for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(selectedSiteName == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
{


}
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

JOptionPane extends JComponent.

Methods of JOptionPane
1) .showMessageDialog(); // VOID :-( 
2) .showInputDialog(); // return STRING :-)
3) .showConfirmDialog(); // return int :-)
-> and more...

Example:

```
void myMethod() {

        JDialog jd = new JDialog();
        jd.setDefaultCloseOperation(1);

        JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane();
        int val = jop.showConfirmDialog(jd, "Hello");
        if(val == 0) jop.showMessageDialog(null, "Success", "INFO", jop.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        System.out.println(val);

        jd.add(jop);

    }
```

Helpful link:
- [Why does JOptionPane.getValue() continue to return uninitializedValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286679/why-does-joptionpane-getvalue-continue-to-return-uninitializedvalue)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html