# Why does JOptionPane.getValue() continue to return uninitializedValue

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

Below are my code

```
public static void main(String args[]){
     JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();
     pane.showInputDialog(null, "Question");
     Object value = value.getValue();
     System.out.println(value.toString()); --> this will print out uninitializedValue

}
```

I basically want to detect when the user click the cancel in JOptionPane and when the user close the JOptionPane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this:

```
    String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Question");
    System.out.println(s);
```

This will return a `null` string if the pane is closed or Cancel is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

`showInputDialog` is a static method, it does not modify the `JOptionPane`. As dogbane points out you should check the return value `showInputDialog`.

Some compilers generate warnings if you call static methods on instances, so always check compiler warnings. In your case call the method like this:

```
String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Question");
if(result == null){
//chancel pressed
}else{
//normal code
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, however dogbane answer first so I will mark his answer as the correct answer. Thank you again +1